# PowerShell Open a shared folder as another user

Tags: powershell, process.start

I've written a GUI in PowerShell Studio for our IT service desk guys. This GUI app is published in Citrix and opened with their administrator credentials. In the app there's a button to query the active directory for a user's home folder. This folder can only be opened with the administrator credentials provided to start the app.

```
$linklabelTSHomeFolder_Click = {
    Start-Process $linklabelTSHomeFolder.Text
}
```

This opens the explorer and says that the location can't be found.. However, I suspect that the opened explorer is opened with their current credentials, not the administrator ones.

When testing with providing the correct credentials I can't get the explorer to open the destination share:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe' -ArgumentList $linklabelTSHomeFolder.Text -Credential $Credentials
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe' -ArgumentList $linklabelTSHomeFolder.Text -Credential $Credentials -Verb runas
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\explorer.exe' -ArgumentList $linklabelTSHomeFolder.Text -Credential $Credentials -Verb runas -LoadUserProfile -WorkingDirectory 'C:\Windows\System32'
```

I've tried literally everything, but I can't get it to open.

Even when I try to run it on my local workstation in the PowerShell ISE with my normal credentials and providing the CmdLet the administrator credentials it isn't spitting out an error, nor is it showing the explorer. Only when I remove the part `-Credential $Credentials` it does open the explorer or spit out an error.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Vista, Windows does not allow an explorer window to be opened with a different user than the current one. `runas` functionality has been stripped. See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/06/28/and-so-this-is-vista.aspx) for more info.

Shift + Right click and `Run as different user` (GUI only) still works.

There is however a workaround to access a share with another user but involves messing with the registry:

```
$regKey ="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\advanced"
$user = $env:username
$domain = $env:userdomain
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regKey -Name SeparateProcess -Value 1
net use \\$args\c$ /user:$domain\$user
explorer.exe \\$args\c$
```

Comment: Thank you Rubanov, in this case I'll just use another [tool](https://explorerplusplus.com/) to open the share.